# Prove that $n^4−1 $ is divisible by 5 when n is not divisible by 5.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Apparently the easiest method is to use proof by exhaustion, but I've no idea how. Any ideas/solutions?
Prove that $n^4−1$ is divisible by 5 when n is not divisible by 5.